# Error generating chart: User memory limit exceeded in Google Earth Engine

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine

I am using "GFS: Global Forecast System 384-Hour Predicted Atmosphere Data" to extract relative humidity data. But while executing my codes it showing 'user memory limit exceeded'. This same codes working for extracting rainfall and temperature data from "ERA5 Daily Aggregates - Latest Climate Reanalysis Produced by ECMWF / Copernicus Climate Change Service". Please guide me in this regard.

Thanking you

*Warm Regards*

*Ratnesh Karjee*

```
//Import GFS: Global Forecast System 384-Hour Predicted Atmosphere Data
var imgHum = ee.ImageCollection("NOAA/GFS0P25")
               .select('relative_humidity_2m_above_ground')
               .filterDate('2018-01-01', '2020-12-31');

var relHum = imgHum.map(function(imgHum){
             return imgHum.clip(JNP)
             });


var relativeHumidity = ui.Chart.image.series(relHum, JNP,
        ee.Reducer.mean(), 5000)
        .setOptions({
          title: 'Humidity of Jaldapara',
          vAxis:{title: 'rainfall (m)'},
          hAxis:{title: 'Days/Months'}
        });
print(relativeHumidity)
```

Comment: Your code can't be run because you haven't provide the clipping geometry `JNP`. Your problem maybe related to `clip` within `map`. see here: https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/best_practices#if-you-dont-need-to-clip,-dont-use-clip